# ?Why getting NaN in the editor on the right side of the slider value of the GapRange in the mono script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

a bit long but the scripts are connected.

propertyattribute

```
using UnityEngine;

public class GapRangeAttribute : PropertyAttribute
{
    public float minRange;
    public float maxRange;
    public float sensitivity;

    public GapRangeAttribute(float minRange, float maxRange, float sensitivity)
    {
        this.minRange = minRange;
        this.maxRange = maxRange;
        this.sensitivity = sensitivity;
    }
}
```

propertydrawer

```
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

[CustomPropertyDrawer(typeof(GapRangeAttribute))]
public class GapRangeDrawer : PropertyDrawer
{
    float minRange;
    float maxRange;
    float sensitivity;

    public GapRangeDrawer(float minRange, float maxRange, float sensitivity)
    {
        this.minRange = minRange;
        this.maxRange = maxRange;
        this.sensitivity = sensitivity;
    }

    public override void OnGUI(Rect position, SerializedProperty property, GUIContent label)
    {
        if (property.propertyType == SerializedPropertyType.Float)
        {
            EditorGUI.BeginProperty(position, label, property);
            EditorGUI.Slider(position, property, minRange, maxRange, label);
            property.floatValue = RoundValue(property.floatValue);
            EditorGUI.EndProperty();
        }
        else
        {
            EditorGUI.LabelField(position, label.text, "Use [GapRangeDrawer] with float values only!");
        }
    }

    private float RoundValue(float value)
    {
        return Mathf.Round(value / sensitivity) * sensitivity;
    }
}
```

the mono script where i'm using the GapRange attribute and the gap variable.

```
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

public class CubeSpawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject cubePrefab;
    public LayerMask terrainLayer;
    [GapRange(0, 100, 0.1f)]
    public float gap = 0f;
    public float cameraMoveSpeed = 5f;
    public float zoomSpeed = 5f;
    public float rotationSpeed = 10f;
    
    private Vector3 lastCubePosition;
    private bool isDragging = false;

    private void Update()
    {
        HandleCameraMovement();
        HandleCameraZoom();
        HandleCameraRotation();

        Vector3 mousePosition = Input.mousePosition;
        
        HandleRuntimeInput(mousePosition);
    }

    private void HandleRuntimeInput(Vector3 mousePosition)
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            isDragging = true;
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(mousePosition);
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out RaycastHit hitInfo, Mathf.Infinity, terrainLayer))
            {
                lastCubePosition = hitInfo.point;
                GenerateCube(lastCubePosition);
            }
        }
        else if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
        {
            isDragging = false;
        }
        else if (isDragging && gap > 0f)
        {
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(mousePosition);
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out RaycastHit hitInfo, Mathf.Infinity, terrainLayer))
            {
                if (Vector3.Distance(hitInfo.point, lastCubePosition) >= gap)
                {
                    GenerateCubesBetween(lastCubePosition, hitInfo.point);
                    lastCubePosition = hitInfo.point;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void GenerateCube(Vector3 position)
    {
        float terrainHeight = Terrain.activeTerrain.SampleHeight(position);
        Vector3 cubePosition = new Vector3(position.x, terrainHeight, position.z);
        Instantiate(cubePrefab, cubePosition, Quaternion.identity);
    }

    private void GenerateCubesBetween(Vector3 start, Vector3 end)
    {
        float distance = Vector3.Distance(start, end);
        int numCubes = Mathf.RoundToInt(distance / gap);

        Vector3 direction = (end - start).normalized;
        float stepSize = distance / numCubes;

        for (int i = 0; i < numCubes; i++)
        {
            Vector3 position = start + direction * (i * stepSize);
            GenerateCube(position);
        }
    }

    private void HandleCameraMovement()
    {
        float horizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float vertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        Vector3 moveDirection = new Vector3(horizontal, 0f, vertical);
        moveDirection.Normalize();

        transform.Translate(moveDirection * cameraMoveSpeed * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);
    }

    private void HandleCameraZoom()
    {
        float zoom = Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel");

        Vector3 zoomDirection = new Vector3(0f, 0f, zoom * zoomSpeed);
        transform.Translate(zoomDirection, Space.Self);
    }

    private void HandleCameraRotation()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(1))
        {
            float rotationX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * rotationSpeed;
            float rotationY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * rotationSpeed;

            transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, rotationX, Space.World);
            transform.Rotate(Vector3.right, -rotationY, Space.Self);
        }
    }
}
```

what I want to do is to use the gap variable using the GapRange to add gaps between range 0,100 and the third parameter in the attribute the sensitive should set the GapRange slider movement sensitive.

It seems that the problem is in the PropertyDrawer script because the NaN in the inspector showing before running the game.

I also used a break point and saw that the value of floatValue in property.floatValue is NaN so I tried to remove that line but it didn't change much , still showing NaN in the inspector.

the propertydrawer after changes:

```
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

[CustomPropertyDrawer(typeof(GapRangeAttribute))]
public class GapRangeDrawer : PropertyDrawer
{
    public float MinRange { get; set; }
    public float MaxRange { get; set; }
    public float Sensitivity { get; set; }

    public GapRangeDrawer()
    {
        MinRange = 1f;
        MaxRange = 100f;
        Sensitivity = 0.1f;
    }

    public override void OnGUI(Rect position, SerializedProperty property, GUIContent label)
    {
        if (property.propertyType == SerializedPropertyType.Float)
        {
            EditorGUI.BeginProperty(position, label, property);
            EditorGUI.Slider(position, property, MinRange, MaxRange, label);
            //property.floatValue = RoundValue(property.floatValue);
            EditorGUI.EndProperty();
        }
        else
        {
            EditorGUI.LabelField(position, label.text, "Use [GapRangeDrawer] with float values only!");
        }
    }

    private float RoundValue(float value)
    {
        return Mathf.Round(value / Sensitivity) * Sensitivity;
    }
}
```

Comment: NaN it's mean val / 0 , so if gap = 0 , it's would happend

Comment: @TimChang the error in the editor in the inspector showing NaN is even before even running the game.  the problem is in the propertydrawer script.  i found that  the floatValue in property.floatValue is NaN so I tried to remove that line but it didn't change much with the NaN in the inspector before even running the game.  edited my question with what I changed in the propertydrawer.

Comment: Why not simply use the `[Range(0f, 100f)]` ? Is it so very important that you round to `0.1` increments? In that case personally I would just go with a `[Range(0, 1000)] int gap;` and later on use `float actualGap = gap / 10f;` ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the main reason is that this constructor

```
public GapRangeDrawer(float minRange, float maxRange, float sensitivity)
{
    this.minRange = minRange;
    this.maxRange = maxRange;
    this.sensitivity = sensitivity;
}
```

and probably not even this one

```
public GapRangeDrawer()
{
    MinRange = 1f;
    MaxRange = 100f;
    Sensitivity = 0.1f;
}
```

might ever be called by the `Inspector` as it creates the property drawer instances internally and probably uses some internal constructor of `PropertyDrawer`!

So the `sensitivity` / `Sensitivity` within your `GapRangeDrawer` will always stay `0`! (Something you can surely confirm yourself by [Debugging your Code](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ManagedCodeDebugging.html)).

---

Also possible that the `NaN` you have right now in the Inspector is just still a result from some failed test before ;)

What you have now actually works for me .. it is still not how you would do something like that.

---

In general this is not how you implement a custom property drawer nor how you access the according property's / attribute's fields. See [PropertyDrawers](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/editor-PropertyDrawers.html) for examples in particular also for attribute drawers.

It depends a bit on how exactly you want to do this.

If you want to pass in the parameters you will want to do e.g.

```
public class GapRangeAttribute : PropertyAttribute
{
    public const float MinimalSensitivity = 0.1f;

    public float MinRange { get; }
    public float MaxRange { get; }
    public float Sensitivity { get; }

    public GapRangeAttribute(float minRange = 0f, float maxRange = 100f, float sensitivity = MinimalSensitivity)
    {
        MinRange = minRange;
        MaxRange = maxRange;
        Sensitivity = Mathf.Clamp(sensitivity, MinimalSensitivity, Mathf.Abs(maxRange - minRange));
    }
}
```

and then in your drawer accordingly access those using

```
[CustomPropertyDrawer(typeof(GapRangeAttribute))]
public class GapRangeDrawer : PropertyDrawer
{
    public override void OnGUI(Rect position, SerializedProperty property, GUIContent label)
    {
        label = EditorGUI.BeginProperty(position, label, property);
        position = EditorGUI.PrefixLabel(position, label);
        
        var range = (GapRangeAttribute)attribute;
        
        if (property.propertyType == SerializedPropertyType.Float)
        {
            EditorGUI.Slider(position, property, range.MinRange, range.MaxRange);
            property.floatValue = RoundValue(property.floatValue, range.Sensitivity);
        }
        else
        {
            EditorGUI.HelpBox(position, "Use [GapRangeDrawer] with float values only!", MessageType.Error);
        }

        EditorGUI.EndProperty();
    }

    private static float RoundValue(float value, float sensitivity)
    {
        return Mathf.Round(value / sensitivity) * sensitivity;
    }
}
```

**OR** if you anyway want to go with fixed values you could make them `const` directly in the drawer itself instead of weirdly passing them in via constructors and do e.g.

```
public class GapRangeAttribute : PropertyAttribute { }
```

and

```
[CustomPropertyDrawer(typeof(GapRangeAttribute))]
public class GapRangeDrawer : PropertyDrawer
{
    const float MinRange = 0f;
    const float MaxRange = 100f;
    const float Sensitivity = 0.1f;

    public override void OnGUI(Rect position, SerializedProperty property, GUIContent label)
    {
        label = EditorGUI.BeginProperty(position, label, property);
        position = EditorGUI.PrefixLabel(position, label);
        
        if (property.propertyType == SerializedPropertyType.Float)
        {
            EditorGUI.Slider(position, property, MinRange, MaxRange);
            property.floatValue = RoundValue(property.floatValue);
        }
        else
        {
            EditorGUI.HelpBox(position, "Use [GapRangeDrawer] with float values only!", MessageType.Error);
        }

        EditorGUI.EndProperty();
    }

    private static float RoundValue(float value)
    {
        return Mathf.Round(value / Sensitivity) * Sensitivity;
    }
}
```

Comment: still getting NaN in inspector.

Comment: @DanielLip Then it is probably just still a serialized value from some time before .. move the slider or `ContextMenu` -> `Reset` the component ... it works for me (even you way above - it is just not how you would do it) ;)